# Purification of classical-quantum state

Tags: cq-states, purification

For a classical-quantum state in $\mathcal{H}_{X \otimes A}$
$$
\rho = \sum_x p(x) \vert x\rangle \langle x \vert \otimes \rho^x,
$$
I can use spectral decomposition for $ \rho^x $ to get $$
\rho^x = \sum_{i_x} \lambda_{i,x} | i_x \rangle \langle i_x|,
$$ and obtain $$
\rho = \sum_{x,i_x} p(x)\lambda_{i,x} \vert x\rangle \langle x \vert \otimes | i_x \rangle \langle i_x|,
$$ then if we introduces new system $C$ with basis $\{|\alpha_{x,i_x}\rangle\}$,
then $$
|\psi \rangle = \sum_{x,i_x} \sqrt{p(x) \lambda_{i,x}} |x \rangle | i_x \rangle | \alpha_{x,i_x} \rangle
$$ is purification of $\rho$.
But I wonder whether there is other purification of $\rho$ that makes use of properties of such a classical-quantum state to get a more beautiful form of purification.

Comment: This might be as far as you can go - if you stick to the classical-quantum decomposition, you need to purify each of the $\rho^x$ individually without reference to the other terms in the sum, so you just get a convex combination of your states of the form $|x\rangle |i_x\rangle$ in general (which you know how to purify due to orthogonality)